# %dopar% in R does not work properly

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, plyr

I just start to use the foreach and %dopar% methodes for parallel processing in R , but the results I'm getting are confusing and not the same as a for loop; here is the code I used to test those methodes and resultes I'm getting:

```
library(plyr); library(doParallel); library(foreach)

cs <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cs)

sfor_start <- Sys.time()
s_for=as.numeric()
for (i in 1:1000) {
  s_for[i] = sqrt(i)
}
print(Sys.time() - sfor_start)

sdopar_start <- Sys.time()
sdopar=as.numeric()
foreach(k=1:1000) %dopar% {
  sdopar[k] = sqrt(k)
}
print(Sys.time() - sdopar_start)
```

And here the results:

```
> s_for[1:10]; sdopar[1:10]
 [1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068 2.449490 2.645751 2.828427 3.000000 3.162278
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you try `sdopar <- foreach(k=1:1000) %dopar% { sqrt(k) }`?

Comment: Works fine with .combine=c, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read the documentation of functions before saying that they don't work.

`foreach` works more like a `lapply` than a `for`-loop.

So, for example, `foreach(k=1:1000) %dopar% sqrt(k)` gives the same result as `lapply(1:1000, sqrt)`.

Yet, it is true that you can modify global variable when using `foreach` **SEQUENTIALLY**. Yet, when using parallelism, the vector `sdopar` is copied to each "cluster" so that you modify a copy, not the initial object.

So, you'll have to do as mentioned by @ChiPak with option `.combine = c` or using `do.call(sdopar, c)` afterwards.

PS: Always initialize the vector you fill iteratively (for efficiency of not growing a vector), for example like this: `s_for <- double(1000)`.