# R : Parallel processing on matrix and list

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am new in R and I'm really confused with parallel operation in it. For example I have simple code like this:

```
 MyMat<- matrix(0,counter,2)
  for(i in 1:(c-1)){
    for(j in (i+1):c)
    {
      in <- (i-1)*c-(i*(i+1)/2)+j
      MyMat[ind,1] <- i
      MyMat[ind,2] <- j
    }
  }
```

I like to run this code as parallel. I tried some codes like this

```
cl<-makeCluster(4) 
registerDoSNOW(cl)
MyMat <- foreach(i=1:(c-1), .combine=c) %dopar% {
  for(j in (i+1):c)
  {
    ind <- (i-1)*c-(i*(i+1)/2)+j
    MyMat[ind,1] <- i
    MyMat[ind,2] <- j
  }
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

It created multiple process as I check in TaskManager, However, I did not get the correct answer. MyMat is a Null list after foreach. Also I tried to return MyMat after for loop but because of  `.combine=c` I get concatenated list, NOT A MERGED MATRIX FROM EACH CLUSTER.

Also I want to know how code I do parallel processing on lists? I did have tried some codes like this:

```
tempList <- list(1,2,3)
tempList[[1]][2]<-5
tempList[[3]][2]<-4

cl<-makeCluster(4) 
registerDoSNOW(cl)
tempList <- foreach(i  =  iter(tempList))  %dopar% {
    if(length(i)>1){
        i[3] <- i[1] +i[2]
    }
  i
} 
stopCluster(cl)
```

However the if condition in foreach does not work properly. It returns

```
tempList:
1  5
2 
3  4
```

Nothing happens on list!!! But if I remove the condition I will get this result:

```
tempList:
1  5  6
2 NA NA
3  4  7
```

Comment: About your final comment, `foreach` returns a list by default. You have it returning a matrix when you use `.combine=rbind`. For example, try `foreach(i=1:10) %do% (i + 1)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I still have problems with condition in foreach. I will edit the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [%dopar% in R does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573255/dopar-in-r-does-not-work-properly). See my answer there.

Comment: No .combine = c does not work for me. It just returns concatenated list, not a merged matrix from each cluster